# How to edit instances inside a binding list?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i have this bindinglist:

```
private static BindingList<Player> players = new BindingList<Player>();
```

it contains 6 objects which do everything I want them to do

What I am trying to do is get the location of each of the objects and change some parameters in other objects depending on the objects location. 
like this

```
private void playerpositions
{
   int location;

   for each player in players

     location = players.location
     ctrl = MapSquareNumToTablePanel(location)
     crtl.containsplayers = true
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  You can set a value on a player in your list the same way as you would if it's not in a list.  They are references.  So in your loop just do `player.Property = newValue;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using WRONG syntax here:

```
      location = players.location
```

You must use:

```
      location = player.location
```

So, your code should be:

```
{
   int location;
   foreach (list player in players)
       {
       location = player.location;
       ctrl = MapSquareNumToTablePanel(location);
       crtl.containsplayers = true;
       }
```

}

Comment: thanks Dave, how would I go about writing the `for each player in players` part?

Comment: See above edited code...  Anyway, I believe you´re a little bit confused about VB.NET and C# - your syntax is mixing both of them. See this link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach

Comment: I was just doing a mock up of the code i was trying to write, thats why it looks like vb

Comment: What would the FOR loop equivalent be?

Comment: I believe you can´t perform LIST´s in a common FOR-NEXT, but if so, you may utilize the index like players(0).location, players(1).location and so forth - just this.